# How do I use regex to replace a string in node?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm having difficulty replacing the string using the following code.

Basically I have a .php file and I'd like to overwirte some constants using the [replace package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace).

The results from the following code are as follows:

```
//results in 

define('DB_NAME', 'foo'); //original (as defined in config.php)

define('DB_NAME', 'bar''bar'); //actual result 

define('DB_NAME', 'bar'); //desired result

var replace = require("replace");


var defineSetting = function(name, value){
    replace({
        regex: "'DB_NAME', *",
        replacement: "'DB_NAME', 'bar'",
        paths: ['wordpress/wp-config.php'],
        recursive: false,
        silent: true,
    }); 
}

defineSetting("DB_NAME", "testDatabase2");
```

How do I get the desired result I'm looking for?

Comment: You should never overwrite CONSTANTS - that is why they are called that.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's for when I initially create a project. It's not intended for creating modifying through a project. I would be manually changing these constants when I set up a new project anyway.

Comment: If you're changing them when you perform the setup why would you need to ask about REGEX for this? It's not totally clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex: `regex: "'DB_NAME', .*"`

Comment: Can you add an explanation to help me out please? It works but I'm not sure why I need the period before the wildcard. Thanks.

Comment: `.` is the wildcard for regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html `*` is a repetition operator: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: A problem, this answer produces: `define('DB_NAME', 'bar'` (It's erasing the `);`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
regex: "'DB_NAME', [^)]*",
```

The reason you're not replacing *"foo"* is because your regex is matching *"'DB_NAME',"* followed by zero or more spaces. Which leaves the rest `'foo');` intact.

---

*Explanation:*

`[^)]*` says match zero or more characters that are NOT a close paren `)`.

`[^]` is a regular expression negative character class group. This means match characters that are not in this list of characters.